# How to change the background section

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, collectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, uicollectionreusableview

I have a collection view and I want to add a image to the background but I want that the imagen change depending the section.

I`m changing the header and I can modify the header depending the section but I can´t make the same with the background of the section.

This is my background decoration:

```
class SectionBackground: UICollectionReusableView {
    
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension SectionBackground {
    func configure() {
        
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "categorias_cat_1_base")
        
        imageView.frame = self.bounds
        
        addSubview(imageView)

    }
}
```

I`m using the method 'viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind' but i can`t use it for the background I tried to check the kind but there isn`t any kind for the section background.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `uicollectionviewcompositionallayout` in your question, I am presuming that's the layout you are using. Adding a background to a section is fairly straightforward.

1. Define an ElementKind struct in your code

   ```
    struct ElementKind {
        static let background = "background-element-kind"
        //other element kinds such as header and footer kinds can be added here as well
    }
   ```
2. While you are configuring your compositional layout for the collection view in question, insert this sample code in the appropriate place.

   ```
    let sectionBackground = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind: ElementKind.background)
    section.decorationItems = [sectionBackground]
   ```
3. Lastly, when you are finished with configuring the UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout, you have to register the decoration view with the layout. You need to do something like this:

   ```
    let myCustomLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section) //or whichever initializer you are using 
    myCustomLayout.register(SectionBackground.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: ElementKind.background)
    return myCustomLayout
   ```

Cheers!